# NestJS populate only populates first element

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, mongoose, nestjs

I have a Mongoose schema in NestJS like such:

```js
...
@Prop()
  casinoAmount: number;

  @Prop()
  gameHyperLink: string;

  @Prop()
  casinoHyperLink: string;

  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Game' })
  games: Game[];
}
```

I want to make a query, that makes a full " left join". Basically a query that select each `Provider` with all elements from the corresponding games.

If i do a regular query (without `populate`) it will simple return all the `ObjectID's`

```js
    const providers = await this.providerRepository
      .find({})
      .skip(offset)
      .limit(limit)
      .exec();
```

[image: Example payload]

However when i populate like such

```js
    
const providers = await this.providerRepository
      .find({})
      .populate('games')
      .skip(offset)
      .limit(limit)
      .exec();
```

[image: Payload with games]

However, it only returns a single `game` object and not a list of all the objects.

Does anybody know why this occurs?

Answer (score 1):

first of all don't use `exec()` when you are using await for query and use `skip()` and `limit()` like this as option in the populate:

```
await this.providerRepository.find({}).populate({
    path:'games',
    options: {
        limit: limit,
        skip: skip

    })
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The code did not work properly i tried with this query and it worked 
```const provider = await this.providerModel
      .findOne({})
      .populate('games', null, Game.name);
```

Comment: but if you use skip and limit after populate, it's always return first item, for your query, with skip and limit, do it work correctly?